# How can I implement Koppen's climate classification in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am about to start a project to make a map showing the climate zones in US. I am given a dataset of the climate, but my next step is to make a separate layer of each of the climate groups defined by Koppen.

For example, Group B: dry climates is defined by little precipitation, and according to Wikipedia, it can be calculated by completing the following steps.

Multiply the average annual temperature in Celsius by 20, then add

(a) 280 if 70% or more of the total precipitation is in the spring and summer months (April–September in the Northern Hemisphere, or October–March in the Southern), or
(b) 140 if 30%–70% of the total precipitation is received during the spring and summer, or
(c) 0 if less than 30% of the total precipitation is received during the spring and summer.

Assume that I already have all the data I need for this calculation such as the amount of precipitation, what tool in ArcGIS would I need to complete this calculation?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would open the table containing your climate data and then create a new field (Add Field), making it an integer. Then right click over the head of the new field and use the Field Calculator to make the calculation. I would suggest selecting the 70% records first and performing the addition of 280, then the 30-70% next and adding 140, etc. on the basis of the final values of this field, you could then add another field and populate it with the climate type depending on the criteria.

Not really very clear what your dataset is or if it is linked to shapefiles. If so, what do the shapefiles represent?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have not actually seen what my data looks like, but I will check tomorrow and come back to you!

Comment: OK, my data is raster datasets, so it does not have attribute table. I think I can use raster calculation to do it.